# Configuring deployment of SSAS multidimensional cube to different environments

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssas, cube, sql-server-data-tools

I have seen this answer [Deploying SSAS cube to environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309835/deploying-ssas-cube-to-environments)

Which describes how deployment of a SSAS cube can be automated, however what I can't see is how to configure the project to be able to deploy to multiple environments i.e. Development, UAT and Production, where each is on a different server and has a different data source.

I can see in the Visual Studio SSDT Analysis Services project that the configuration manager can be used to set multiple deployment configs in the **USER SPECIFIC!!** .dwproj.user file.

This allows me to set multiple SSAS deployment locations and when building for DEV or UAT etc.. the .deploymenttargets file gets set correctly.

What this doesn't do is allow me to set a different data source automatically during a build to auto change the .configsettings file.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the dwproj file holds the different SQL connection strings per environment as described here:
http://www.artisconsulting.com/blogs/greggalloway/2008/3/19/analysis-services-project-configurations

I have seen a bug when you first set this up that the dwproj file is never flagged as dirty so those connection string changes are never saved to disk. If you have an issue with this I usually add a new Role object then immediately delete it. That marks the dwproj file as needing to be saved.

Comment: Thanks thats a great little blog post. What I can't see is if there is a GUI available to modify the connections that are being stored in the dwproj file? do you know if there is?

Comment: It is easier than you are thinking. Just flip the Visual Studio configuration drop down to Dev or Prod (it pays attention to which is selected) then edit the connection string as you normally would by double clicking the data source object in Solution Explorer. (The do the add then delete role trick I mentioned above.) Then click the Save All button.

Comment: Ok cool I'll try that and then set this as the answer once I've checked it.. Thanks a lot